# A variable used in javascript without being defined. Need clarification

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am new to Javascript. I found this code from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel):

```
// When the user hits return, send the "text-entered"
// message to main.js.
// The message payload is the contents of the edit box.
var textArea = document.getElementById("edit-box");
textArea.addEventListener('keyup', function onkeyup(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    // Remove the newline.
    text = textArea.value.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
    addon.port.emit("text-entered", text);
    textArea.value = '';
  }
}, false);
// Listen for the "show" event being sent from the
// main add-on code. It means that the panel's about
// to be shown.
//
// Set the focus to the text area so the user can
// just start typing.
addon.port.on("show", function onShow() {
  textArea.focus();
});
```

I wonder whether there is something wrong with the `text` variable? how is it used without being defined? is this acceptable in Javascript? can you clarify please?